# Find distance between 3d point and 3d curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I have a 3 dimensional curve given by the equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0 \end{bmatrix} +t\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}+t^2\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ g \end{bmatrix}$$

How do I find the smallest distance between this curve and a vector like$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$. I tried to calculate distance in terms of t and take the derivative but it got very complex very quickly. Is there a simpler way of doing this or do I need to just keep plugging away at the derivative?

Comment: use the distance squared. The square root sign does not help in finding the best $t$ value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have
$$\vec{p}_0 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\ z_0 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{p}_1 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{p}_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{q} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix} \right ]$$
and a curve $\vec{p}(t)$,
$$\vec{p}(t) = \vec{p}_0 + t \vec{p}_1 + t^2 \vec{p}_2 = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_0 + t x_1 + t^2 x_2 \\ y_0 + t y_1 + t^2 y_2 \\ z_0 + t z_1 + t^2 z_2 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
The squared length of the vector from point $\vec{q}$ to point $\vec{p}(t)$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
s(t) &= (\vec{p}(t) - \vec{q}) \cdot (\vec{p}(t) - \vec{q}) \\
\;     &= (t^2 x_2 + t x_1 + x_0 - x)^2 + (t^2 y_2 + t y_1 + y_0 - y)^2 + (t^2 z_2 + t z_1 + z_0 - z)^2
\end{aligned}$$
If you expand the above, you get
$$s(t) = C_4 t^4 + C_3 t^3 + C_2 t^2 + C_1 t + C_0$$
where
$$\begin{aligned}
C_4 &= x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2 \\
C_3 &= 2 x_1 x_2 + 2 y_1 y_2 + 2 z_1 z_2 \\
C_2 &= x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 + 2 x_2 (x_0 - x) + 2 y_2 (y_0 - y) + 2 z_2 (z_0 - z) \\
C_1 &= 2 x_1 (x_0 - x) + 2 y_1 (y_0 - y) + 2 z_1 (z_0 - z) \\
C_0 &= (x_0 - x)^2 + (y_0 - y)^2 + (z_0 - z)^2
\end{aligned}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{aligned}
C_4 &= \vec{p}_2 \cdot \vec{p}_2 \\
C_3 &= 2 \vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{p}_2 \\
C_2 &= \vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{p}_1 + 2 \vec{p}_2 \cdot (\vec{p}_0 - \vec{q}) \\
C_1 &= 2 \vec{p}_1 \cdot (\vec{p}_0 - \vec{q}) \\
C_0 &= (\vec{p}_0 - \vec{q}) \cdot (\vec{p}_0 - \vec{q})
\end{aligned}$$
$s(t)$ reaches an extremum (minimum or maximum value) when its derivative is zero, i.e.
$$\frac{d\,s(t)}{d\,t} = 4 C_4 t^3 + 3 C_3 t^2 + 2 C_2 t + C_1 = 0$$
This is a cubic equation in $t$, and has zero, one, two, or three real roots $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  The [algebraic solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Algebraic_solution) are known.